# How to add line breaks in a query (Informix)?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, informix

I need to do a query that updates text with a line break. I tried using `\n` but it inserts "\n" literally.

Example:

```
update table set text = "first line\nsecond line"
```

I want it to show that text as:

```
"first line
second line"
```

and not as `"first line\nsecond line"`.

When I do this with .NET it works, but not on a stored procedure.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I can't find the Informix command equivalent to Oracle's CHR, so you could use: `CHR(10)CHR(13)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might, perhaps, be looking for the function '[ifx_allow_newline](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1570.htm)'.

Alternatively, following the suggestion of OMG Ponies, you might be looking for the package '[ascii](ftp://ftp.iiug.org/pub/informix/pub/ascii.tgz)' from the IIUG Software Archive.  Informix now has the functions [ASCII()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1555.htm) and [CHR()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1952.htm) built-in.  Note that if you have older versions of Informix (anything before 11.50 — 11.70 for `CHR()`), these functions will not be available and you will need to consider the package from the IIUG archive.

Comment: @alk: The version 10 documentation that was linked to has been moved during the last 7+ years.  The current version (12.10) is available at: [`ifx_allow_newline`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1570.htm).  This too may change in 7 years time.

Comment: Oh, well, hadn't looked at the date. Please excuse. Thanks anyway! :-)

Comment: @alk: I've updated this answer with links to the Informix 12.10 documentation.  Thank you for pointing out the problem.  27 more answers to fix up…

Answer (score 5):

To use a «new line» character inside a SP:

```
(...)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE IFX_ALLOW_NEWLINE('T');
SELECT FIRST 1
    REPLACE('Lets use a breakline here#and here#for example', '#', '
')
FROM systables;
(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'Wibble' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Wobble'
```

Puts in the carriage return and the new line like \r\n in C#.  You might want both if the text is ever going to be exported into a document anywhere because sometimes just newline -\n char(10) - appears as a box character for some very dreary reason that I've forgotten/never really got :-)

Comment: this is cool, but the thing is that I need to create the string on a stored procedure, not on .net

Comment: This does not work inside Informix; the `+` operator is not used for string concatenation.  It might work in some client software.

Comment: The string concatenation operator in Informix is double pipe: "||"